# Why are SQL Server Table-Valued Functions listed in sys.indexes?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

As a quick background I've been tasked with moving tables and indexes off of the PRIMARY filegroup onto other filegroups.  In order to get an idea where everything already lives I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT s.name AS schemaName, o.[name] AS ObjectName, 
i.[name] indexName,
CASE o.[type]
    WHEN 'U' THEN 'User Table'
    WHEN 'S' THEN 'System Table'
    WHEN 'TT' THEN 'Table Type'
    WHEN 'IT' THEN 'Internal Table'
    WHEN 'TF' THEN 'Table Valued Function'
    ELSE o.[type]
    END
AS objectType, 
f.[name] AS [FileGroup]
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.filegroups f
ON i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects o
ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id] 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
ORDER BY s.name, o.name, i.name
GO
```

Running this I see that user defined table-valued functions also show up in here and are listed with a type description of 'HEAP'.  Why is that?  Is data actually being stored in the same way tables and indexes are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every table has an physical organization. If there is no user-specified *clustered* index, the table is stored as a heap, otherwise it is stored according to the clustered index.

This is true of tables, user-defined table types, and functions that return table-types. The index rows you're seeing for table-valued user-defined functions reflect the organization of the *anonymous* table type defined in the function's preamble.

I happen to have a lot of user-defined table types, but only two table-valued user-defined functions...and saw the same heap index entry for those table types as well. The indexes for these entities appear to all be unnamed - which seems appropriate.

With a user-defined table-valued function, you typically accumulate data in the declared table and return them at the end...so SQL has to know how to store the data during execution. User-defined *inline* table-valued functions lack indexes, as would be expected, since such entities are effectively parameterized views using the indexes of the underlying objects.

**Edit**:

You can add limited indexes to the anonymous tables defined in the declaration of the user-defined, table-valued functions - as well as user-defined table types.

Comment: Small correction: a table is a heap table if there is no clustered index. A heap table can have any number of non-clustered indexes.